VLA type parameter vs simple pointer
VLA type parameters is very useful when passing multidimensional arrays to functions, but do we get any benefits when passing one dimensional arrays?
Consider the two following prototypes
void func1(const uint8_t *data, size_t size);
void func2(size_t size, const uint8_t data[size]);

Does the second have any benefits over the first one?
Can the compiler maybe issue more warnings if the second is used?

There's really no difference. data will be a pointer in both cases.

func2 could be declared as void func2(size_t size, const uint8_t data[static size]); which declares that the first size elements of the array pointed to by data must be accessible, otherwise there will be UB.

The main benefit is that a static analyzer - a program used to check code quality beyond mere C language conformance - could compare the function arguments against those expected an signal errors in case they mismatch.
Whereas C compiler needn't do that, because passing array[whatever] to a function expecting array[size] is conforming due to function parameters getting adjusted to a pointer to the first element, and losing type information in the process. The compiler could provide additional diagnostic if is in a helpful mood.
Example using gcc 14.2:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void func1 (const uint8_t *data, size_t size)
{}

void func2 (size_t size, const uint8_t data[size])
{}

int main()
{
  uint8_t array[3] = {1,2,3};
  func1(array, 5);
  func2(5, array);
}

Diagnostics:

warning: 'func2' reading 5 bytes from a region of size 3 [-Wstringop-overread]

But not a word about func1 call doing the very same thing.

Thanks then I see no reason to not use the func2 style, except maybe supporting pre C99 compilers.

@Fredrik The func1 style is kind of traditional/idiomatic C though, since that's how we've passed arrays to functions since the dawn of time. I think both forms are fine and an actual static analyzer with access to main() as well as func1() ought to spot out of bounds bugs present. Whereas for example clang doesn't warn for either function no matter how many warnings I enable (maybe expecting you to run clang-tidy for such bug-spotting purposes).

(Btw C11 or C17 compilers need not support VLA either, in case they insist on being low quality implementations. But in ISO C23 they must support the posted code.)

The static analyzer is just guessing what the programmer intended in this case. To make it explicit, it should have been declared as const uint8_t data[static size].
